# Use a write protected USB drive

Tags: linux, usb, read-only

I've got an old Win10 installation USB installation media. It's a pretty nice USB stick and I would like to reuse it, but no matter how I try to mount it, it always shows as read-only. I guess Microsoft must have put some sort of write protection on their installation media (maybe so that unexperienced users would not accidentally delete imporant files?).

I, however, want to write to it, how can I "unlock" in Linux? I hope that the protection is just a software switch, but is there a way to confirm that it is not locked at the hardware level?

Comment: I have made Windows 10 USB keys and then re-used them without issue. Try formatting the USB key to clear it.

Comment: @John I have not made it, it's the USB stick that came with the box when I've bought the license. I cannot format it because it mounts as read-only

Comment: The manufacturer may have made it read-only in some way you cannot clear it (so it is always available later when needed).  Just use a different USB key.

Comment: It's not like USB keys are expensive. I can get a USB-2  128 GB flash drive in the UK for £10.98 (around $15). To go to USB-3 is around 50% more.

Comment: Some USB keys have a little physical switch for that.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I can't use another one. I need it quite in a hurry and that's the only one that I could use. In the time that I can get one I won't need it anymore